# "Forward search" methods for outlier detection etc. in regression

Tags: regression, outliers, robust

I am reading *Robust Diagnostic Regression Analysis* by Anthony Atkinson and Marco Riani. They propose a robust "forward search" method for detecting outliers and other problematic data in regression (various sorts of regression are covered in the book).

Briefly, they start with a very small number of observations that are clearly not problematic and gradually add observations, then they graph various statistics (such as $\beta$ values) against the number of observations.

This approach makes a lot of sense to me, but I am interested in any problems with it. Googling did not reveal much and most of it was by Atkinson or Riani or their colleagues.